# In Android, how do I recognize an input field of an application as a password field?

Tags: android, input, types, field

In Android, how do I recognize an input field of an application as a password field?

I see this related question:
why do Google apps have TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD in non-password input fields

The answer to that question does not answer the above question. Is the answer to test for TYPE_TEXT and TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD?  Are the google apps just an exception?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, let me clarify.  I'm writing an input method and while the input method is connected to an edittext in the browser displaying a signon page, the editorinfo showed the TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD bit set while I was connected to a user name field.  Is  that a bug in the browser app?

Comment: Its either a bug or an intended hack (they want to take advantage of some behavior that usually occurs in password fields).  Or a bug in the html.  In the end, you can't really do anything other than trust the type and shrug.

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  I've pointed Browser at a number of sites and it shows that bit set on all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(txt.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD || 
                    txt.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD || 
                    txt.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD || 
                    txt.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD) {


// Yes, It is a Password Field. Do Something

}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Yes, this is what you would expect to work.  It makes sense except for the behavior of Browser.